# mysql_query and embarcadero c++

Tags: c++, mysql, unicode, c++builder, wchar-t

I use MySQL C API with Embacadero c++ without any problems in (ANSI). 
But when I try to send any wide character (UNICODE) like Arabic symbols, appears as not readable characters (garbage) in MySQL database. Because the SQL string that I send it by mysql_query function must be (const char *) and not (const wchar_t *).

for your notes:
I'm talking about (INSERT statement) in MySQL.

thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

What Collation use for this Database ?

You must to use utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci

[image]

Comment: inside the mysql db there is no problems.. ofcourse I used the utf8_general_ci collation. but mysql_query function just accept char* parameter, and I need wchar_t to INSERT into DB.